# Filter Songs(Data) according to chechbox selected

Tags: android

filter data according to selected checkbox from database table "song" that I have created in SQLite database (fk for(artist, album, genre, tempo) is defined in song table)and the year is column in song table). What I want to do is when I select a value from spinner it will save the id of that particular value into checkbox.

And show those filter song in a listview. guide me how to do it. sequence step?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
case R.id.btn_show_selected_song:
  if(cbArtist.isChecked()==true){
     mSelectedArtist = (Artist)spArtist.getSelectedItem();
     Long id = mSelectedArtist.getMartist_id();
   }else if(cbArtist.isChecked()==false){
     Toast.makeText(SelectedListActivity.this,"Button is Disable",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  break;
case R.id.chech_box_artist:
  if(cbArtist.isChecked()){
    spArtist.setEnabled(true);
  }
}
 else{
  spArtist.setEnabled(false);
 }
break;
```